# In which memory format the variables are stored?

Tags: php

I am getting into the very basics of PHP, and suddenly came across a thought of "In which memory format the variables are stored in memory?"

Is that a Stack or Heap?

Please provide me a reference material to study this variable allocation in memory..

Comment: What do you mean by "format", can you make an example?

Comment: Now what do you mean by "the type of memory"?

Answer (score 3):

PHP uses `zval/pval` as the basic data container.

```
struct _zval_struct {
    zvalue_value value;     // The value
    zend_uint refcount__gc; // The number of references to this value (for GC)
    zend_uchar type;        // The type
    zend_uchar is_ref__gc;  // Whether this value is a reference (&)
};

typedef union _zvalue_value {
    long lval;                // For integers and booleans
    double dval;              // For floats (doubles)
    struct {                  // For strings
        char *val;            //     consisting of the string itself
        int len;              //     and its length
    } str;
    HashTable *ht;            // For arrays (hash tables)
    zend_object_value obj;    // For objects
} zvalue_value;
```

They are defined in zend.h: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend.h#318